# How to set the title of Kendo.Window() in jQuery if the window is defined in a separate project level .js file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have a page where I call a java script to open a popup. This pop up is defined as a `Kendo().Window` in common `.js` file for an application.

On the page I have a `jQuery` that opens a pop up om `.Ajax` success:

```
var dialog = $("#myWin").data("kendoWindow");
$("#dWin").html(result);
dialog.open();
```

And in a common .js file I define the window:

```
$("#myWin").kendoWindow({
    visible: false,
    modal: true,
    //title: "Details Report",
    open: function (e) { $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden"); },
    close: function (e) { $("html, body").css("overflow", ""); },
    draggable: false,
    width: 850,
    height: 430,
    position: {
        top: 100,
        left: 500
    },
    resizable: false
});
```

Before, I had this code on each page, where I was able to define its oww window with a title. Now, I moved it to a common file and need to set the specific title related to each page. I looked up in the `inspect element` window, that the title id is `win_wnd_title` and tried to set the title like that:

`$('#win_wnd_title').val("Specific Title");`

But that did not work.

What is the best way I can accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the answer:

`$('#win_wnd_title').text("Specific Report");`